# How to connect Database

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db, zend-studio

Thanks for previous replies

How to connect mysql to zend framework. i created table in mysql. i used

`$config = array(host'     => 'localhost',username' => 'userName','password' => 'sqlpass',
    'dbname'   => 'databasename',$db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $config);
print_r($db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM tablename"));` this command to connect with database, but whenever i tried this, nothing is displayed. Is there any tutorials to connect database with zend framework. i am new to this topic. pls guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$config = array('host' => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'userName',
                'password' => 'sqlpass', 
                'dbname' => 'databasename');

$ResourceDb = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL',$config); 
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($ResourceDb);
```

and now try with fetchAll().

which error do you receive?

Comment: i am getting blank screen.. what is fetchall() function. how to do this..?? i am new to this topic.

Comment: in your application.ini set at 1 flags to display error and exception

Comment: Thanks, now only i knew how to view the errors in zend framework. what can i do in application.ini in order to view the error.

Comment: phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1                                            resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

Comment: okay, Action "index" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()  this is my error..

Comment: i think there is a problem before you try to connect db.. see your MVC cycle if all controllers, action and view are correctly set

Comment: i am directly getting values from view to controller, in controller i fetch the database connection. but still it dint work.

Comment: Invalid controller specified (process)

Comment: Do you have any example that connect simple database with zend framework. i am new to this topic. once i got perfect tutorial i can able to manage with database connectivity. if you have any example pls do share.